# Is the expression "un paese dell'est" usual?

Tags: prepositions, phrase-choice

I have read the following sentence in a learning tool:

> Il Giappone è un paese dell'est.

Is that a usual way of expressing this idea in Italian? "Il Giappone è un paese orientale" or "Il Giappone è un paese dell'est [aggettivo]" (e.g., "asiatico") sounds more natural to me.

Could "in" be used instead of "di"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes and no. *X è un paese dell'Est* is quite a normal sentence, but mostly used to mention countries of Eastern Europe, the former socialist republics (Soviet Union, Poland, Hungary and so on). It *could* be said of Japan too, but it sounds quite unusual. As you suggest, you may say

> Il Giappone è un paese orientale

or

> Il Giappone è un paese dell'Asia orientale

or even

> Il Giappone è un paese dell'Estremo Oriente.

<sub>It's more a convention than a firm rule, but you often write *est* with an upper-case initial when denoting a geographical area (*i paesi dell'Est*), with a lower-case initial when denoting just a direction (*da qui dobbiamo andare per 20 chilometri verso est*). Something similar holds for *oriente*.</sub>